# Function Not Completeing Before Loop

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, asynchronous

I'm trying to pass an array of url's into this function in node.js, and it seems to loop through the URLs before actually passing them into the function. Here is the code that calls the function:

```
async.eachSeries(validDatesArr,
    function(validDatesArrItem, callback){
    var newMonth = validDatesArrItem.getMonth()+1;
    loadPage(baseURL+'/month='+newMonth+'&day='+validDatesArrItem.getDate()+'&year='+validDatesArrItem.getFullYear(),function(data){
        loopThroughData(data, function(){
            var d = validDatesArr[count];
            d.setDate(d.getDate() + 1);
            validDatesArr.push(d);
            count++;
            callback();
        });
    });
    }, function(err){
        if(!err){
            console.log('We processed each date requests one by one');
        }
    }
);
```

The function I'm working with is loadPage. As you can see, I add a day to the date variable each time, and then pass the URL with the modified date into the loadPage function. I'm struggling to get everything to work sequentially. It seems that the rest of my code is going in order, but I can't get this particular one to pass the URL, wait for the function to finish, and then pass the second URL. I thought that was the point of the async.eachSeries function.

So to recap, I want to:

1. Call the loadData function on the first URL
2. Wait for that function to finish
3. Continue (which adds to the date and loops to run the loadPage function again).

Here is the loadPage function code:

```
 function loadPage (url, callback){
    data = [];
    request(url, function(err, response, body){
        if(!err && response.statusCode ==200){
            console.log('Loading URL: ',url,' into Cheerio.');
            var $ = cheerio.load(body);
            $('td', 'tbody').each(function(){
                var text = $(this).text();
                data.push(text);
            });
            callback(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please take a look at javascript Promises. `async` library is a pretty old and ugly solution. After you understand the Promises concept, you will quickly resolve your question using Promise queue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume `request` is an asynchronous function. Therefore, this function is running in a separate thread. The program continues to execute without waiting for the request to complete, creating the effect described. Try either finding a synchronous function, or implementing something like a semaphore in Java to make sure the program waits for the `request` to finish.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but aren't all functions in node.js asynchronous? I was under the impression that I needed to add some sort of counter or callback to make it work.

Comment: It seems based on my testing that the `$('td', 'tbody').each(function(){` section of the code is the part that I need to make sure completes before continuuing.

Comment: @fullOfQuestions Yep. But the callback doesn't make it synchronous as far as I know. The callback is like a `try { return } catch {}` statement. It returns an error or a result. But to make it synchronous a callback is not enough.

Comment: "Therefore, this function is running in a separate thread" - there are **no threads** in user code in Node.js.